# SSL with other sites on same server

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I have a VPS with a dedicated ip. I host several websites on this server. Can I have a ssl certificate on one of the websites, and still host the other websites on that same ip? The other websites does not require ssl. I'm asking because I read that ssl's require a dedicated ip.

Edit: I'm using apache in a lamp setup.

Comment: I believe this belongs to server fault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a distinct IP address per HTTPS host+port (or, to be precise, per certificate, because some certificate may have multiple Subject Alt. Names) because the client cannot tell the server which host it wants (and thus which certificate should be used) when it connects to the HTTPS port, unless you're using Server Name Indication (which is an SSL/TLS extension that seems more and more supported).

The plain HTTP virtual hosts run on a different port (usually 80) than the port used for HTTPS (usually 443) and are not affected by this restriction.

Even if you're not using SNI (in which case you're restricted to using one certificate per IP+port), you can have as many plain HTTP virtual hosts as you want.

A configuration like this should work (specify the port number in the `VirtualHost`):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost www.name1.example:443>
        ServerName www.name1.example

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/...
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/...
        ...
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# (optional)
<VirtualHost www.name1.example:80>
        ....
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost www.name2.example:80>
        ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think I can say that a your answer means YES (it's maybe not completly clear). He can run several domain on port 80 and 1 on port 443, no SSL problem in that configuration. Problems will arise when trying to get several domains in HTTPS.

Comment: @regilero, indeed, sorry if I wasn't clear. My answer meant that yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don not mention what web server you are using about e.g. IIS, Tomcat etc?
Generally speaking you can configure a web server to require ssl for **some** of the web sites it is hosting e.g you can do this in IIS.
In Tomcat you have to enable the ssl connector and configure it to use your certificate.
In this case the access to the web site must be from the secure port. The sites requiring plain http can still function

> ssl's require a dedicated ip

Well depends on what you mean. Usually certificates are issued to an IP or FQDN but it is not mandatory. The pitfall is that if your web clients check on the hostname and the certificate subject name they may reject connection.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using Apache in a standard LAMP setup.

Answer (score 0):

SSL certs work on a per IP basis. You need your sites to have seperate IPs if other sites needs SSL later on.

Comment: This is wrong information.It is the server that is authenticated not the individual web sites it hosts

Comment: @user76686: how is this wrong? a server with 10 IP's can host 10 different virtual hosts each with it's own SSL certificate.

Comment: @user76678: actually, it's one certificate per IP+port combination (unless you're using SNI). I guess it depends on what you call a "web site".

Comment: @Bruno:You are right.You can have different certificates per port.But still it is for the same IP and this certificate per port can be used for multiple web apps deployed by the same endpoint

Comment: @user76678, sure, it's what you said "the server that is authenticated not the individual web sites" that wasn't clear. One server (the actual machine) can have multiple (virtual) hosts and can also have multiple IP addresses (which may or may not match the number of virtual hosts).

Comment: Worth keeping in mind when hosting web sites on non-standard ports (80/443) is that you should not expect corporate clients being able to access the sites. No or at least very few corporate proxies have firewalls port open on non-standard ports. But it does work for home use or dev/testing purposes.